# difference in russian language pack between OSX and Ubuntu, how to get the same output for strftime?

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu-14.04

I am running into an issue with the use of Russian dates in python.

When I run the following on a local OSX virtualenv with python 2.7.9:

```
import locale
import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
temp = datetime.date(2015, 8, 11)
print temp.strftime("%d %B %Y")
```

The output is:

```
11 августа 2015
```

When I run almost the same code on an Ubuntu server in a virtualenv with python 2.7.9:

```
import locale
import datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
temp = datetime.date(2015, 8, 11)
print temp.strftime("%d %B %Y")
```

The output is different

```
11 Август 2015
```

Where does this difference come from and is there a way to force one implementation over the other?

When using strptime this difference is causing errors when the wrong implementation is used since the formats do not match.

Comment: What happens if you use the same locale in each code? (Granted, I wouldn't expect different month names between the UTF-8 and non-UTF-8 code, but you do leave yourself open to that possibility by using different locales.)

Comment: I will try now, but by default using ru_RU.utf8 on max osx gives an error, so  I will have to install that first. Nevertheless, I do not think that makes a big difference, since it is not an encoding issue, or is it?

Comment: I have changed it on both to ru_RU.UTF-8 this does not change the output, I have also changed this in the code above

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is any standard for the contents of a locale, only for the elements used in naming them. (Although you can informally blame one OS or the other, depending on which of the two month variations is "more" correct; my Russian is nearly non-existent, so I couldn't say.)

Comment: The difference is more likely due to the locale version (possibly via the C library version) but I don't know how to find out what you have on OSX. I would expect Apple to be a few years behind but maybe I'm just being prejudist.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same case with `strftime` on OSx and Ubuntu. I solve it with `django.utils.formats`:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import formats
temp = datetime.date(2015, 8, 11)
print formats.date_format(temp, 'DATE_FORMAT')
```

There are some default date formats like 'DATE_FORMAT', 'SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT', but you also can define your own format in Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rely on consistent locales, you'll have to keep your own dictionary of month names:

```
import datetime
months = { ..., 8: 'Август', ... }  # Fill in all 12 with correct names
temp = datetime.date(2015, 8, 11)
print temp.strftime("%d {0} %Y".format(months[temp.month]))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will go with this solution if I cannot get it fixed via locale off course. Are you sure there is no way to get it fixed with the locale setting?

Comment: Not if the locales can vary from machine to machine.